# What's wrong with this line when doing a declaration

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using HeidiSQL to connect to MySQL 5.7.14

I've researched how to declare a variable, but it's giving me this error. Even when on its on.

Does anyone know what is wrong with this?

Thanks

```
DECLARE total_sale INT;
```

[Screen Shot Entire SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZdvs.png)

Comment: `DECLARE` can only be used in procedures.

Comment: Please consider including the error message you got as text instead of a screenshot, so that it is searchable by others.

Answer (score 2):

`DECLARE` is used in programs.  As the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare.html) states:

> DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.

You can simply set the value:

```
SET total_sale = 0;
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that but now I get this error: 

"Unknown system variable 'total_sale'"

Comment: you `SET` the variable after declaring it between `BEGIN` and `END`. Perhaps you should be asking how to do something rather rather than just assuming this is what you want (XY problem). [user variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) are different.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. 
And sorry, I've been thrown in at the deep end here at work. I did spend an hour reading the documentation you linked to, but it is confusing to someone who has never used MySQL before.